# python code for string re-arrangement

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with python code which  transforms the  word/string as follows  Move all consonants before the vowels - The consonants and vowels should be in the reverse order of the original. - If two equal letters come next to each other in the result (case insensitive duplicates),   drop the second letter in the source.

I tried this:

```
def vowels(x): 
    vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"] 
    if x in vowel: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 

def transform_word(word): 
    result = "" 
    if word is not None: 
        x = len(word) - 1 
    v = "" 
    c = "" 
    while x is not -1: 
        if (vowels(word[x])): 
            v += word[x] 
            x -= 1 
        else: 
            c += word[x] 
            x-=1 
    result = c + v 
    result = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(result)) 
    return result
```

Comment: We are not a free homework service.

Comment: I tried this:def vowels(x):
    vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    if x in vowel:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def transform_word(word):
    result = ""
    if word is not None:
        x = len(word) - 1
        v = ""
        c = ""
        while x is not -1:
            if (vowels(word[x])):

                    v += word[x]
                    x -= 1
            else:

                    c += word[x]
                    x-=1
    result = c + v
    result = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(result))
    return result

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: @Anna Edit your question and add your code in the question, and ensure it is properly formatted. Explain exactly what it is that is not working in your code

Comment: @Anna OK. Great. Now explain what is not working. Do you get any error messages. Does the code work but you are getting an unexpected output? You *need* to provide a [mcve] here.

Comment: How to remove case sensitivity? the output for the code I wrote is transform_word("helloBabe") ==bBlheao ; but I need Blheao

Comment: Use either `.upper()` or `.lower()` to make everything the same case

Comment: @Farhan.K  , If I use .upper() or .lower(), case sensitivity cannot be preserved, the output would be transform_word("helloBabe") ==BLHEAO, but I need the output to be Blheao

Comment: You could re-write `vowels` function to this: `def is_vowel(x): return x.lower() in {"a","e","i","o","u"}`

Answer (score 0):

Should work, more or less what you had concept wise, with worse far worse string concatenation.

```
def isvowel(ch):
     if ch in ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", 'a','e','i','o','u']:
          return True
     else:
          return False

vowels = []
consonants = []

for letter in word:
    if isvowel(letter):
        vowels.append(letter)
    else:
        consonants.append(letter)
result = ''

for consonant in consonants:
    result+=consonant
for vowel in vowels:
    result+=vowel
print result
```

Comment: I assume you mean `upper()` instead of `toupper()`

Comment: I'm not sure that's better string concatenation. Adding each character to a list and using string join is the best approach